# How do you perform form action within a modal?

Tags: jquery

I have a bootstrap modal that pops up a form to confirm whether a user wants to delete their account. However, the form action isnt working. The same form action is working outside of the modal. below is just an example of console log not even working:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteUserModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteUser" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn ortho-btn-teal" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <form class="delete_user_account" action="some-endpoint" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
               <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="myval" placeholder="Enter email" style="display:none">
              </div>
             <button id="user-delete-account" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" userId="myid">Delete account</button>
          </form>       
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).on('submit', '.delete_user_account', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("this doesnt log out...")
});
```

on click does work on the button itself, but i need the form action to be triggered (in html - i dont want to do that in jquery with ajax).

Answer (score 0):

type="submit" was needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use click event and trigger submit inside

https://api.jquery.com/submit/